# Install trigger for google app script in custom addon

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-addon

I am still very new to addons and I am having trouble to install triggers and have the related functions to run.

Below is the function to add 1 "on open" trigger and 1 "on edit" trigger to the sheet.

```
function addTriggers() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getUserTriggers(sheet);

  if(triggers.length!=2)//
  {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('sheetOpen')
    .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
    .onEdit()
    .create();

    ScriptApp.newTrigger('sheetEdited')
    .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
    .onOpen()
    .create();     
  }
```

Then I tried to install this function through `onInstall()`;

```
function onInstall(e){
  addSpreadsheetEditTrigger(); 
  sheetOpen();
}

function sheetOpen()
{
//do something after the sheet is open;
}

function sheetEdited()
{
//do something when the sheet is edited by user;
}
```

When I tested this addon, the triggers were not installed and thus none happened. Also please note that I need to use installable triggers because I need to access external files.

Could someone let me know where I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. How to build a trigger manually

If you want to build a trigger for a spreadsheet, you need to specify as parameter in `forSpreadsheet()` the **spreadsheet**, not the **sheet**!

So:

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
...

    ScriptApp.newTrigger('sheetOpen')
    .forSpreadsheet(spreadsheet)
    .onOpen()
    .create();
...
```

2. It seems that you got the assignment of the functions `'sheetOpen'` and `'sheetEdited'` the wrong way around
3. You should doublecheck either you really need to build the trigger manually. Instead you can call the already existing onOpen(e) trigger (unless you need an installable one).

Sample:

```
function onInstall(e){
  sheetOpen();
}
function onOpen(e){
  sheetOpen();
}
function sheetOpen()
{
//do something after the sheet is open;
}
```

### UPDATE

Now, the limitations of Addons won't allow you to install triggers directly. Instead, you can create a custom menu giving the user the option to install the triggers when choosing the respective option.

Sample:

```
function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e); 
}
function onOpen(e) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('MyAddOn Menu')
  .addItem('Please click here to get started', 'addTriggers')
  .addToUi();
}

function addTriggers() {
  ...
}
```

Comment: 1. You are right about the spreadsheet. 2. Could you elaborate a bit on your comment #2? 3. Yes, I do need the installable triggers because I need to access external files and use methods such as openById

Comment: Your trigger run `'sheetOpen'` `onEdit` and `'sheetEdited'` `onOpen` - given the names I assume that maybe you wanted to do the opposite?

Comment: I will but it is still not working... I don't think any of those functions fired and if I use the builtIn onOpen trigger then it will throw an error because it won't allow me to use `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()`.

Comment: I updated my answer to explain how to link the functions.

Comment: I see. That makes sense. Thanks again for helping!

Comment: I extremely value your answer and comment, however I am still stuck. When my addTriggers function ran - it failed, and I am also confused how will letting users manually press a button like Yes, No, override Google's preventative measures since you're still going to have an If statement that will execute the same exact code, except later? I am confused at this part. What changes after they press yes, that allows us to do it directly, vs not being able to do it directly beforehand? @ziganotschka

Comment: Thank you for your interest. Unfortunately I cannot understand your question about "Yes" and "No". I recommend you to create a new post describing your issue more in detail. If a function failed - you should provide the exact error message and the code line that gives you this error.