# Configuring an Installable Trigger in Apps Script for a Company Wide Add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-workspace

So I have created a G Apps Script and I need to manually install the onEdit trigger. However I ran into an authorization issue, so now I am trying to do it this way. I am following the following suggestionfrom a previously asked StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61314827/install-trigger-for-google-app-script-in-custom-addon). However when I look into my execution logs, my onOpen runs but I never get a pop up or any ui show up. Please advise how to correctly setup installable onEdit trigger for an editor-addon that utilizes elevated AUTH mode.

```
function onInstall(e)
{
      onOpen(e); 
}
function onOpen(e)
{
  let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createAddonMenu()
  .addItem('Please click here to get started', 'addTriggers')
  .addToUi();
}

function addTriggers()
{
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('myOnEdit')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onEdit()
      .create();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out my issue, basically the `.createAddonMenu()` is not the same as `.createMenu()` because the Addon one was hidden and all I had to do was go in there and press it.