# Correct way to implement Installable Triggers in Google Addon (Google App Script)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google app script which is published as a Google Sheets add on.  One of the features of the add on is that it take a value of a cell, queries a Google Big Query table, and populates the next cell with a drop down of options.  Once the user selects an option another query is sent to Big Query and so on.

Because this activity happens when a a user edits a cell I think I need to use `onEdit()` type functionality.  However the documentation makes clear that I can’t use `onEdit()` to make such requests that require authorisation (I use a service account) so I need to use a trigger, and because it’s for an add on I need to use an Installable Trigger.

I do this programmatically as per the [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically)

```
/**
 * Creates a trigger for when a spreadsheet opens.
 */
function createSpreadsheetOpenTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('stu')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onEdit()  //the docs actually is onOpen()
      .create();
}
```

In turn, function `stu` gets the values from the cell and calls another function which queries Big Query:

```
function stu(e) {
  var activeCell = e.range;
  var cellValue = e.value;
....
....
if (wsName === "Targets" && c < 7 && r > 1) {
    var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Targets");
    var rowValues = ws.getRange(r, 1, 1, 6).getValues();
    runQuery(cellValue, r, nextCol, rowValues);  // runQuery executes the BigQuery query
  }
}
```

There are a couple of problems that I have come across:

1. It seems that it is not possible to get the installable trigger to install when a user installs the add on.  To get around this I have followed advice at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61314827/install-trigger-for-google-app-script-in-custom-addon  and added a menu item to allow the user to install the trigger.
2. I have started getting errors such as `Exception: This add-on has created too many edit triggers in this document for this Google user account.`

Can anyone advise if I am correct in creating an Installable trigger onEdit

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger('stu')
          .forSpreadsheet(ss)
          .onEdit()
          .create();
```

Perhaps instead I should be using

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger('stu')
          .forSpreadsheet(ss)
          .onOpen()
          .create();
```

and then in function `stu` wrap the functionality in an `onEdit()`:

```
function stu(e) {
  onEdit(e) {
    var activeCell = e.range;
    var cellValue = e.value;
   ....
   ....
   if (wsName === "Targets" && c < 7 && r > 1) {
     var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Targets");
     var rowValues = ws.getRange(r, 1, 1, 6).getValues();
     runQuery(cellValue, r, nextCol, rowValues);  // runQuery executes the BigQuery 
   query
  }
 }
}
```

If I am correct in using an Installable Trigger should I be deleting previous instances in order to avoid the `Exception: This add-on has created too many edit triggers in this document for this Google user account.`  error?  I can see that there is a way to check for the existence of triggers and delete as appropriate (also on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually).

I suspect that actually I am fundamentally understanding how I should be using installable triggers.  I've read through the docs, but any advice much appreciated.

Comment: `deleting previous instances` Why are there previous instances? There should be only 1 trigger. Were you executing the create trigger function many times?

Comment: @StuartBrown Add-ons are limited to one and only one installable trigger.

Comment: @TheMaster,  I think that is one of my mistakes. I think my code creates an installable trigger each time a user edits. Is the option I propose of creating the IT onOpen and then putting onEdit in the function I call in the trigger better?

Comment: @TheAddonDepot sorry I was only able to tag one person in my reply. Do you think I should switch to creating the trigger onOpen and use onEdit inside the function it calls?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will make just one:

```
function creatonedittrigger(funcname) {
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == funcname).length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger(funcname).forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive()).onEdit().create();
  }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks @Cooper. Do you think I want to create the trigger onEdit or onOpen? If I create it onEdit will it try to create the trigger each time the user makes an edit (which will presumably generate many triggers). If I use onOpen the trigger gets created once (and your logic handles removing additional instances on future opens), and the I then put the onEdit in the function that the trigger calls

Comment: That function will only allow the creation of one trigger for the given handler function name.  But I would not attach it to any trigger.  I would just run it once and forget about it.  You you wish get an onEdit trigger once for every user edit so you will probably wish to limit it's action to one sheet at a time.  There are a lot of examples of onEdit functions on this site.  Try running this inside the trigger `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))` where e is the parameter use for accepting the event object.  There are quite a few more things in the event than are documented.

Comment: Many thanks. I'll give this a go when I get home from work this evening!