# Apps script installable trigger isn't called

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

Iwas trying to install and trigger a simple onEdit trigger, but it didn't show can effect.

Than I've tried to install an installable onEdit2 trigger - but it won't seem to fire when I debug calling "foo"/

Is there a caveat?

```
function foo() {
let trigger = createInstallableTrigger("myTrigger", "onEdit2", "every time a cell is edited", onEdit);
trigger.create();

trigger = ScriptApp.getTrigger("myTrigger");
trigger.install();
}



/**
 * The event handler triggered when editing the spreadsheet.
 * @param {Event} e The onEdit event.
 * @see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite
 */
function onEdit2(e) {
  // Set a comment on the edited cell to indicate when it was changed.
  const range = e.range;
  range.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date());
}
```

Comment: Your example is not reproducible because we do not have the code for ` createInstallableTrigger(` so we can't help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct way to implement Installable Triggers in Google Addon (Google App Script)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70340731/correct-way-to-implement-installable-triggers-in-google-addon-google-app-script)

Comment: Where did you get your code for `function  foo()`? It looks like the kind of thing that ChatGPT would serve up - a combination of non-existent and irrelevant commands. It always pays to read (or at least browse) the documentation. In this case, you would have found [forSpreadsheet(sheet)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder#forspreadsheetsheet) and a complete example of the script.

Comment: @Tedinoz I cannot remember, however - why does a simple onEdit() simple trigger won't be called?

Comment: @EladBenda could you share a sample script for the onEdit() trigger, also, what operation are you performing in Google Sheets that is supposed to trigger it?

Comment: "To use a simple trigger, simply create a function that uses one of these reserved function names" [doc Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#getting_started). You ask `why does a simple onEdit() simple trigger won't be called?` - it is because a simple `onEdit trigger` must be named **onEdit** - yours is named `onEdit2`.

Comment: @Tedinoz Thanks, but I've origianlly used `onEdit()` and not `onEdit2()`, only then I retried with version2 as an installed trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Function `foo` appears to be an attempt to programmatically create a *installable* `onEdit` trigger. I suspect that it is sourced from ChatGPT because it contains both irrelevant (`createInstallableTrigger`) and illegal (`trigger.install()`) function calls.

OTOH, the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onedit) includes a simple example of the script for an installable `onEdit` trigger.

---

```
/**
 * Creates a trigger for when a spreadsheet is edited
 */
function createSpreadsheetOnEditTrigger() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
ScriptApp.newTrigger("onEdit2")
  .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
  .onEdit()
  .create();
}
```